# How to get selected values from multiple dropdowns on button click using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to `console.log()` multiple values from five different dropdowns on a button click. I have done this for one dropdown, but I don't know how to do it for more. I'm still a beginner.

Here's my code:

```
export default function Suma() {

  const typedemande = [
    { value: "first", label: "first" },
    { value: "second", label: "second" },
    
  ];

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  

  const handleChange = event => {
    setMessage(event);
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(message);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-lg">

        <Select placeholder="choose" id="message" className="react-dropdown "  name="message" onChange={handleChange}

          value={message}
          isClearable
          isSearchable={false}
          classNamePrefix="dropdown"
          options={typedemande}

        />

      </div>
      <div className="text-center">
        <button className="mr-2 btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for this one:

```js
export default function App() {
  const typedemande = [
    { value: "first", label: "first" },
    { value: "second", label: "second" },
    { value: "third", label: "third" },
    { value: "fourth", label: "fourth" },
    { value: "five", label: "five" },

  ];

  const [showAll, setShowAll ] = useState([]);

  const [dropdowns,setDrodowns] = useState({
    'message1': '',
    'message2': '',
    'message3': '',
    'message4': '',
    'message5': '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
      setDrodowns({...dropdowns,[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
  }

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you use the element inside `form` then it would prevent to submit
    console.log(dropdowns);//to log the values in console
    setShowAll(Object.values(dropdowns));// to show the changes in UI
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-lg">

        <Select
          name="message1"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={"second"}
          options={typedemande}
        />
        <Select
          name="message2"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={"second"}
          options={typedemande}
        />
        <Select
          name="message3"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={"second"}
          options={typedemande}
        />
         <Select
          name="message4"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={"second"}
          options={typedemande}
        />
         <Select
          name="message5"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={"second"}
          options={typedemande}
        />

      </div>
      <hr/>
      <ul>
        { showAll.map((val,i)=><li key={i}>{i+1} --- {val}</li>) }
      </ul>
      <hr/>
      <div className="text-center">
        <button className="mr-2 btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For details check the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-proskuriakova-iyr3v7?file=/src/App.js)

[Out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUfBL.png)

***Edit: Based on user comments I edited the answer***

Comment: FYI [there is a snippet you can use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) to secure the code on this site rather than codesandbox.

Comment: @Andy thanks, next time definitely I will use that

Comment: @SKG I tried the code, it gets the job done, but how can I just log the values without getting them in a ul, and also I have a problem, it refreshes on button click, I see the values for 1 second and it refreshes,

Comment: @soulayka I have edited the answer, check the `handleClick` function, if you don't want to see the changes in UI then remove the 3rd line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to your `handleChange`.

```
const handleChange = (event, position) => {
  console.log(position);
};
```

```html
<Select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 1)} />
<Select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 2)} />
<Select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 3)} />
```

Comment: But I want to pass the value selected not the position, how can I do that?

Comment: Use `event.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

Improving axtck's answer, you can get each select value like below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export function App(props) {


  const typedemande = [
    { value: "first", label: "first" },
    { value: "second", label: "second" },
    
  ];

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  

  const handleChange = (event, pos) => {
    console.log(pos)
    console.log(event.value)
    let mz = [...messages];
    if (mz.length > 0 && mz.findIndex(msg => msg.index == pos) > -1) {
      mz[mz.findIndex(msg => msg.index == pos)] = event.value;

      setMessages(mz);
    }
    else {
      mz.push({
        index: pos,
        value: event.value
      });

      setMessages(mz);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
      console.log(messages[i].value)
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-lg">

        <Select placeholder="choose" id="message" className="react-dropdown "  name="message" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 1)}

          value={messages[0] ? messages[0].label : ''}
          isClearable
          isSearchable={false}
          classNamePrefix="dropdown"
          options={typedemande}

        />

        <Select placeholder="choose" id="message" className="react-dropdown "  name="message" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 2)}

          value={messages[1] ? messages[1].label : ''}
          isClearable
          isSearchable={false}
          classNamePrefix="dropdown"
          options={typedemande}

        />

      </div>
      <div className="text-center">
        <button className="mr-2 btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );


}
```